# Bind temporary rvalue to reference lvalue in std::vector constructors

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference, lvalue, rvalue

Until now, I thought that we cannot pass a temporary rvalue to a lvalue reference. But just recently, I took a closer look on the fill constructor of std::vector:

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

`const value_type& val` is a reference lvalue and `= value_type()` is a anonymous rvalue, in my understanding. Why is it possible? Isn't the temporary rvalue immediately destroyed, so that the reference has nothing to point to?

Comment: "I thought that ..." / but / "Why is it possible?" - because you thought wrong: the key point is that only a `const` reference *can* be so bound, and in doing so prolongs the lifetime until the end of the relevant scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant part of the standard is in [class.temporary] (`§12.2/5`in N4140):

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of
>   the full-expression containing the call.

So the temporary `value_type()` will be bound to `val` and will persist for the duration of the constructor.

Comment: Your answer and Tonys comment are somewhat inconsistent. Tony suggests that the const is the crucial point, however, what you say sounds as it is generally valid, also for non-consts. Who's right?

Comment: @user1494080 Tempoaries can be bound to to const lvalue-references and rvalue-references. Both rules apply for those cases.